# GeneXus Extension: List properties of all Generators in a KB - (PropertyName, PropertyValue)

Tags: sdk, genexus

I need to iterate through all the properties of all the generators of a KB in a GeneXus Extension.

I would like to understand how the KB / Version / Environment / Models / Generator are modeled in Gx16 and Gx17.

Does anyone have an example in C# of how to list the properties of a generator?

To list the properties of the KB, I am using the code:

```
foreach (Property kbp in UIServices.KB.CurrentKB.Properties.Properties)
   {
    string kbpvalue = "";
    if (kbp.Value != null)
         kbpvalue = kbp.Value.ToString();
    writer.AddTableData(new string[] { "KB", kbp.Name, kbpvalue, kbp.IsDefault.ToString()}) ; 
   }
```

I need the equivalent to Generator properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All properties are handled through the `PropertiesObject` class itself, or eventually subclasses of it.

Accessing KB properties is pretty straightforward, given a `KnowledgeBase` instance, the KB properties are under the `Properties` property. e.g.

```
PropertiesObject kbProps = UIServices.KB.CurrentKB.Properties;
```

Version and Environment properties are modeled in the `KBModel` class which is a subclass of `PropertiesObject`. The difference between a Version and a Environment is that the former has the `Type` set to `Design`, while the later  is `Prototype`.
For a UI package, the most convenient way to access the active Version, and the active Environment is:

```
KBModel design = UIServices.KB.CurrentModel;
KBModel target = design.Environment.TargetModel;
```

Here `design` is a `KBModel` whose `Type` property is `Design`, and it represent the version properties, and `target` is also a `KBModel` but it's `Type` property is `Prototype`. In the SDK you may find that the name `target` referring to a prototype `KBModel` is used interchangeably with `working`.

`DataStore` and `Generator` properties are another thing. Both concepts are represented by KBObjects, so there is a `DataStoreCategory` object and a `GeneratorCategory` object. The peculiarity with these objects, is that they don't have too many properties. The most commonly used properties in DataStores and Generators are properties dependent on the target Environment. In order to access those Environment dependent properties, you can use `GxDataStore` and `GxGenerator` classes, that can be requested to the corresponding model part. e.g.

```
KBModel design = UIServices.KB.CurrentModel;
KBModel target = design.Environment.TargetModel;

foreach (GxGenerator gen in target.Parts.Get<GeneratorsPart>().Generators)
{
    gen.Properties....
}

foreach (GxDataStore ds in target.Parts.Get<DataStoresPart>().DataStores)
{
    ds.Properties....
}
```

The properties in `GxDataStore` and `GxGenerator` are loaded dynamically based on the type of data store or generator. That's the reason for the properties to be under a `Properties` property, and not having `GxDataStore` and `GxGenerator` inherit from `PropertiesObject` themselves.

The last thing to mention, all these names are valid in GX 17. For generators particularly, there was a big rename in APIs from GX 16 to 17, due to the names used in the previous version not aligned properly with the conceptual model. The details of everything that was renamed from GX 16 to 17 is [summarized here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?46392,Extensions%20and%20Patterns%20Compatibility%20in%20GeneXus%2017).